# What are the verdicts of law suits in Law & Order Special Victim Unit?

Tags: law-and-order-svu

I started watching Law & Order Special Victim Unit from season 1. I noticed there is a mini plot next to the major story line in each episode, and the mini plot normally involves a member of SVU goes to court and testify against a suspect.

E.g.:

1. In episode one, Payback, an inexperienced detective from SVU goes to court and testify again a suspect that sexually harassed a woman who has died. The defence attorney comes up to this detective and asks for the terminology for this type of sexual crime. It is not revealed whether this man is convicted.
2. In episode two, A single life, the African American detective goes to court and testify against a father who allows sexually explicit Japanese cartoon in his house so that this father's son (13 years old) commits a rape later. No verdict is delivered.
3. In episode three, Or Just Look like one, a detective goes to court and testify against another sex offender and gets into a competition with the defence a lawyer over some terminology. No verdict is delivered.

Why?

Comment: I have never really noticed the pattern you describe beyond a few specific single episodes, so I think you might be overgeneralizing here. Can you try to clarify a little more what you're talking about and why you think this is a more general pattern? Or is this just about single lines of dialogue where the characters disappear for a few minutes (and which never *intend* to have any conclusion)?

Comment: I haven't watch much SVU and am probably not going to be much help here, but I am a bit confused about what you are asking. Are you asking why many [first season] episodes have these kinds of subplots or are you asking why these kinds of subplots usually go unresolved/without a verdict?

Comment: I am asking why these of kinds of subplots go unresolved.

Comment: You might have some details mixed up. According to the SVU wikia, "In court, Monique Jeffries argues that a father was raising his son (accused of rape) to condone rape. They had found a Japanese comic book called Rape Man, which is about a superhero who seeks revenge on women by raping them." and that was episode 3. However, it doesn't further explain this. I'd have to watch it myself to see some more context. https://lawandorder.fandom.com/wiki/...Or_Just_Look_Like_One